# Partitions of unity and bump function

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds

> Exercise $13.4$ 
>  *$\quad$ Let $F:N\to M$ be a $C^\infty$ map of manifolds and $h:M\to\mathbb R$ a $C^\infty$ real-valued function. Prove that $\operatorname{supp}(F^*h)\subseteq F^{-1}(\operatorname{supp} h).$*

I can not image this guestion in my mind.can you give me graph and help how ı can prove this question please.

[image]

Comment: Just write down the definition of support and the definition of $F^*h$. You also need to know what the notation $F^{-1}(S)$ means for $S\subset M$.

Comment: ı done what you said but ı am confused that can ı say F(n) in supp(h) ıf yes how ı can say this? @Ted Shifrin

Comment: Well, if $h(F(n))\ne 0$, then doesn't that mean $F(n)\in\text{supp}(h)$? By the way, your definition of support isn't quite right; it needs to be a closed set.

Comment: Okey ı will rewrite my definition of support but if ı can not say F(n) in supp(h) how ı can continue my proof? @Ted Shifrin

Answer (score 1):

It's often easier to work with the complement of support. The complement of support  is the union of all open sets on which the function is identically zero. Think about the following fact:

> If $h$ is identically zero on an open set $U\subset M$, then $h\circ F$ is identically zero on $F^{-1}(U)$.

Then consider taking $U=M\setminus \mathrm{supp}\, h$ here.